# Lipschitz map between hypersurfaces/manifolds

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

if $A$ and $B$ are compact hypersurfaces or manifolds and $F:A \to B$ is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism, does it follow that $F$ is Lipschitz? I am think of the case where these hypersurfaces are boundaries of bounded open sets.

Edit: after reading around a bit about compact manifolds, it seems that this is true. But I wonder if anybody would give me an easy proof of this fact for hypersurfaces  where the language of manifolds is avoided?

Do other properties  such as Rademachers theorem also hold for manifolds?

Comment: Just use the boundedness of $DF$ to bound the length of $F \circ \gamma$ in terms of the length of $\gamma$ for arbitrary paths $\gamma$ in $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest proof is by contradiction. Suppose $F$ is not Lipschitz: then there are two sequences $x_n,y_n$ such that $$\frac{d(F(x_n), F(y_n))}{d(x_n,y_n)}\to\infty$$ The numerator is bounded; thus, the denominator must tend to zero. By compactness of $A$, we can also pass to a convergent subsequence of $x_n$. Say, $x_n\to x$. By the above, $y_n\to x$ also. Whatever definition of a $C^1$ map you use will be violated at $x$.